# How to get Environment Variable inside Angular App running in a Pod?

Tags: angularjs, docker, kubernetes

I have a Angular app made using angular-cli.

I have made a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ngnix
COPY dist /usr/share/ngnix/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Now I want to deploy this image in `minikube`, and also I want to print the Environment variable I passed via `kubectl apply` in the index.html

My problem is how my Angular App will have the access to Environment Variable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Suppose, you are deploying following Pod in minikube to run your app.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: app/angular
    env:
    - name: ENV_1
      value: "value 1"
    - name: ENV_2
      value: "value 2"
```

Lets say, this container will run your app.

**Your question:**

How can you get these ENV inside your Container?

**Answer:**

There is nothing special to do to get these ENVs. All ENVs, you have passed, are now your systems ENV. You can just get them.

In Bash: `echo $ENV_1 $ENV_2`

If you want to print them: `printenv` in bash.

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks that help me! :) 
Can you tell me one more thing, how can I echo the same variable in browser, i.e. index.html, using angular if possible, in the container deployed in minikube.

Comment: I don't know why OP accepted your answer. Their question was how to read the environment variable within the Angular app. Not in bash.